# Reroute HTTP traffic to HTTPS with Node.js Express app running on an Azure

Tags: azure, http, https, routes, port

I have successfully set up my Node.JS Express app (web site) on my Azure virtual machine.  The app is listening on port 7777.  The express app is running in certificate enabled mode with a valid SSL certificate for the web site's domain name.  I have an Endpoint in my virtual machine that maps port 443 traffic to port 7777.  Everything works fine and I can access the web site as long as I use "https://" links.  However, if I try to access the site with plan HTTP links ("http://"), the site can't be reached.

The problem I'm having is figuring out how to set things up so that plain HTTP traffic reaches my app.  If I try to set up an endpoint that maps port 80 traffic to port 777, the Azure console will not allow it because it demands a unique public/private port pair, and port 7777 is already in use with the port 443 mapping endpoint.

It seems like I am very close.  What do I need to do to get Azure to route port 80 traffic to my Node.JS Express app